# Hexadecimal to float IEEE 754 double precision c++

Tags: c++, hex

I'm trying to do a conversion from hexadecimal to float64 in C++ with IEEE 754 double precision.
This is the first time I have played with bits so maybe my code is not clean enough. 
I don't know why my mantissa is giving me strange results but I think I am doing something wrong.

```
long int raw = 0x40000F0000000001;
int sign = raw >> 63;
long int mantissa = (raw & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFF);
mantissa +=1;
double exp = ((raw >> 52) & 0x7FF) - 1023;
double result = pow(-1., sign) * mantissa * pow(2.0, exp);
cout << "MANTISSA: " << mantissa << " EXP: " << exp << endl;
cout << "RESULT: " << result << endl;
```

And the output is:

```
MANTISSA: 16492674416642 EXP: 1
RESULT: 3.29853e+13
```

Anybody know how to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> long int raw = 0x40000F0000000001;
> ```

It is implementation specified whether `long` is long enough to hold that many bits (typically on Windows it isn't, on Linux it is if you compile a 64 bit program, but not 32 bits.)

> ```
> int sign = raw >> 63;
> ```

This line has implementation defined behaviour if the sign bit is set.  (Plausible results are 1 and -1, but there is nothing to stop an implementation specifying "42".)  You would be much better defining `raw` as `uint64_t`

> ```
> long int mantissa = (raw & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFF);
> mantissa +=1;
> ```

This is your problem.  The missing '1' bit is at the *front* of all the bits.  You need to add 0x1000000000000 instead (or better, define a constant `const uint64_t MantissaOffset = 1uLL << 52;` and another `const uint64_t MantissaMask = MantissaOffset-1;` - that way you don't have to count all those `F`s and `0`s.)

You will then have a mantissa that is 2**52 too large (so you need to account for that when calculating the exponent.

> ```
> double exp = ((raw >> 52) & 0x7FF) - 1023;
> double result = pow(-1., sign) * mantissa * pow(2.0, exp);
> ```

... and of course, this doesn't account for denormals, NANs and INFs.

> ```
> cout << "MANTISSA: " << mantissa << " EXP: " << exp << endl;
> cout << "RESULT: " << result << endl;
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to mee that your mantissa is *almost* ok. For `0x40000F0000000001` fraction is `0xF0000000001` (least 52 bits) which is exactly `16492674416641`. To be honest I don't have idea why do you add 1 to it.

If you want a good example how you can play with it, you can see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#Double-precision_examples) wikipedia page. At the end of a chapter there is a very nice example of how to get a double from it's 64-bit raw representation step by step:

```
Given the hexadecimal representation 3FD5 5555 5555 5555(16),
  Sign = 0
  Exponent = 3FD(16) = 1021
  Exponent Bias = 1023 (constant value; see above)
  Fraction = 5 5555 5555 5555(16)
  Value = 2^(Exponent - Exponent Bias) × 1.Fraction – Note that Fraction must not be converted to decimal here
        = 2^-2 × (15 5555 5555 5555(16) × 2^-52)
        = 2^-54 × 15 5555 5555 5555(16)
        = 0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125
        ˜ 1/3
```

Also, note: as you deal with 64-bit values it is safer to use `uint64_t` type which guarantees to be 64 bits size. You can use it by incuding `<stdint.h>` header.

Comment: He's adding '1' because your example code shows `1.Fraction`.  And having extracted lots of 5's, it then uses `15...`  - it's that leading 1 that he is trying to add.

Comment: @MartinBonner Well, then it should be definitely not `+=1` as you already covered in your answer.